# Appending clones of element is causing page to not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have several `div` elements on my page, and I want it so that when you click one, it opens up in a modal. To accomplish this, I am using Javascript to clone and then append each element to a bootstrap modal. The problem is, whenever I try to append the copied `div` to the modal, either using `clone` or by copying the `outerHTML`, the page wont load, and I have to force-quit the tab.

```
for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
var p = projects[i];

// Create modal container
var outerModal = document.createElement('div');
outerModal.id = p.id + "-modal";
outerModal.className += " modal fade";  
outerModal.setAttribute("role", "dialog");

var innerModal = document.createElement('div');
innerModal.className += " modal-dialog";

var p2 = p.cloneNode(true);
innerModal.appendChild(p2);
//console.log(p2);
outerModal.appendChild(innerModal);
document.body.appendChild(outerModal);
p.onclick = function(){$(outerModal).modal("show");};
}
```

What is causing this? I assume something is taking up too much memory or something, but I dont see where.

Comment: Just a quick question...why don't you make 1 modal and when you click the ```div``` you just populate it with the content relevant to the clicked ```div```?

Comment: I guess that never ocurred to me. But I want the modal to have a different id for each div so I can link to it

Comment: That's generally what I do. You create 1 modal, then assign a ```click``` function to each ```div```. Pass an ID into that function and populate the content of the modal based on that.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. I just added an answer. Mark it as the correct answer when you can so someone searching for this issue won't have to read through these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating multiple modals, do this:

1. Create one modal
2. On each of your `div`, add a click event
   that passes in the ID.
3. In the click event, run a
   `switch/case` on it and populate that one modal based on the
   clicked `div`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome you can press Shift+Escape to check memory usage. Also, using console.log to check what it is doing can be pretty helpful.

Can you provide a demo? Something like jsfiddle or similar. I created a quick test page and this appears to be working as far as creating divs with the proper classes.

Here is a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/g9m2w98j/

HTML

```
<div id="outerModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div id="innerModal" class="modal-dialog">
    <div id="modalContent" class="modal-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>
    Text Elements
  </h2>
  <input type="text" name="project" value="Test1"> <br>
  <input type="text" name="project" value="Test2"> <br>
  <input type="text" name="project" value="Test3"> <br>
  <input type="text" name="project" value="Test4"> <br>
  <input type="text" name="project" value="Test5"> <br>
</div>

</body>
```

JavaScript

```
$("[name = 'project']").on('click', function(){
    $('#modalContent').empty();
    $('#modalContent').append($(this).clone(true));
  $('#outerModal').modal("show");
});
```

CSS

```
.modal-content {
  padding: 15px;
}
```